スプレッドシートの条件付き書式が計算されるタイミングはいつなのでしょうか
googleスプレッドシートで設定する条件付き書式が計算処理されるタイミングはいつになるのでしょうか。
例えば以下のスプレッドシートと条件付き書式があったとします。
・シートA、シートBがあるスプレッドシート
・シートAのA:B列に条件付き書式が設定されている
・条件付き書式のルールはセルに"済"と入力されたら対象となる行のセルの色をグレーにする
このような場合、A1やB2に"済"と入力したら条件付き書式の計算が動きセルがグレーになることは当然だと思いますが、次の挙動をしたときに条件付き書式の計算処理は動くのでしょうか？
①スプレッドシートを開いたタイミング
②シートAのC1セルに任意の文字を入力したタイミング
③シートAのA1セルに"無"と入力したタイミング
④シートBの任意のセルに"済"と入力したタイミング
自分の認識では③のみ処理が動くと思うのですが、もし他のタイミングで計算されているとなるとスプレッドシートが重くなる要因になるので見直しをしないといけないと思いドキュメントを確認したのですが

スプレッドシートのパフォーマンスを上げる方法
Google スプレッドシートのパフォーマンスを改善し、計算をスピードアップできます。
条件付き書式ルールを削除する
条件付き書式ルールを確認して、不要なルールを削除するようにします。不要なルールにより、計算速度が低下することがあります。
Google スプレッドシートでスプレッドシートを開きます。
シート全体を選択します。
上部の [表示形式] 次に [条件付き書式] をクリックします。
右側で削除するルールを見つけます。
ルールを削除アイコン 削除 をクリックします。
条件付き書式の計算には時間がかかり、データの範囲全体にすべてのルールが適用されるため、このような最適化は大切です。データ容量が大きくなるにつれ、必要な計算量も増えます。また、条件付き書式ルールは重複したり、相互に上書きしたりすることがあるため、スプレッドシートのパフォーマンスを簡単に改善するには、不要な条件付き書式ルールを削除することをおすすめします。

公式のドキュメンに記載されている

データの範囲全体にすべてのルールが適用されるため

このデータの範囲全体がどの範囲なのかがはっきりわからないため質問させていただきました。

日本語がうまくできませんが答えてみました。

Googleスプレッドシートの条件付き書式設定の計算タイミングについて
Googleスプレッドシートで条件付き書式設定を行うと、その計算はさまざまなタイミングで行われます。以下の各シナリオについて、条件付き書式設定のルールが再計算されるかどうかを説明します。

スプレッドシートを開いた瞬間

はい、スプレッドシートを開くと、条件付き書式設定のルールは再計算されます。これにより、スプレッドシートが読み込まれたときにすべての条件付き書式設定が最新のデータに基づいて適用されます。


シートAのC1セルに任意の文字を入力した瞬間

いいえ、条件付き書式設定のルールで指定された範囲外のセルにデータを入力しても、そのルールの再計算は行われません。今回のケースでは、ルールは列A:Bに適用されるので、列Cの変更は再計算を引き起こしません。


シートAのA1セルに「No」と入力した瞬間

はい、セルA1は条件付き書式設定の範囲（A:B）内にあるため、「No」などの値を入力するとルールが再計算されます。これにより、指定された範囲内の更新が即座に反映されます。


シートBの任意のセルに「Done」と入力した瞬間

いいえ、他のシート（この場合はシートB）の変更は、異なるシート（シートA）に適用された条件付き書式設定ルールには影響を与えません。再計算はルールで指定された範囲とシートに限定されます。



パフォーマンスの考慮
公式ドキュメントには、条件付き書式設定のルールが指定されたデータの範囲全体に適用されると記載されています。これは次のことを意味します：

指定された範囲内のセルにデータを入力するたびに、ルールが再計算され、書式設定が適用されるかどうかがチェックされます。
スプレッドシートを開くときに、条件付き書式設定ルールで指定された範囲全体がチェックされ、正しい書式設定が適用されます。

これを踏まえ、スプレッドシートのパフォーマンスを向上させるためには：

条件付き書式設定ルールが適用される範囲を最小限に抑える。
計算量を増やす可能性がある重複するルールを避ける。
定期的に条件付き書式設定ルールを見直し、不要なルールを削除して計算負荷を減らす。

まとめ
特定のシナリオにおいて、条件付き書式設定の再計算は以下のときに行われます：

スプレッドシートを開いたとき（①）。
指定された範囲内のセルに値を入力したとき（③）。

指定された範囲外や他のシートにデータを入力しても、条件付き書式設定ルールの再計算は行われません（②と④）。この動作により、関連する変更に限定して再計算が行われ、パフォーマンスが最適化されます。


すばらしい回答ありがとうございます！１に関してはまったく想定外で、多人数がスプレッドシートにアクセスするとパフォーマンスが落ちてしまいますね。
